# Netbeans projects tree issue with custom Look and Feel

Tags: java, look-and-feel, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a custom dark look and feel module for Netbeans 8.0.2 and started with customising the project's tree.

I am extending SynthLookAndFeel and below is the synth.xml. It is very basic but the problem starts right here itself. I hope anyone can help me to resolve the issue so that I can start customising other controls as well.

```
<synth>
    <style id="defaultStyle">
        <font name="Tahoma" size="12"/>
        <state>
            <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#262626"/>
            <color type="FOREGROUND" value="#EFEFEF"/>
            <color type="TEXT_BACKGROUND" value="#262626"/>
            <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#EFEFEF"/>
            <color type="FOCUS" value="#0000C0"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="defaultStyle" type="region" key=".*"/>

    <style id="treeStyle">
        <property key="Tree.leftChildIndent" type="integer" value="4"/>
        <property key="Tree.rightChildIndent" type="integer" value="12"/>

        <state>
            <opaque value="true"/>
            <color type="BACKGROUND" value="#131313"/>
            <color type="FOREGROUND" value="#EFEFEF"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="treeStyle" type="region" key="Tree"/>
</synth>
```

The problem is that the tree in project's window does not show the text in #efefef color but tree in other places does. This seems really weird and I am struggling to find any answers from last few days.

**Project's Window**
[image]

**Some Tree in Options Window**
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It could using it's own cell renderer and ignoring the look and feel defaults...

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for you reply. Do you have any idea how this can be fixed?